# Android code error. Application stops unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having a problem with my code. Whenever I run it, it shows the error error `application stopped unexpectedly`. I think the issue is caused by some error in the Java class. What exactly is causing this issue?

Here is my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#A52A2A"
tools:context="com.safeermalik.gpa.Start">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Subject :"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Subject Name"
    android:id="@+id/subject"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Marks :"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Subject Marks"
    android:id="@+id/marks"/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:text="Credits :"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Subject Credits"
    android:id="@+id/credits"/>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Criteria :"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_old"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Old Criteria"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Criteria"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
<Button
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add course"
    android:background="#696969"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/add_table"
   >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Subject "/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Marks "/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Credits "/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Percentage "/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="GPA "/>
    </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Total Marks : "/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/total_marks"
            android:hint="Total Marks "/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="S-GPA : "/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/s_gpa"
        android:hint="GPA "/>
</TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="PERCENTAGE : "/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/final_percentage"
            android:hint="Percentage "/>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Java class:

```
public class Start extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText sub;
EditText mark;
EditText credit;
Button Adds;
int a=0,b=0,hour=0,x=0,counter=0;
String grade="";
String subject="";
EditText SUM,percent,GPA;
double gpa,gpa_multiple;
TableLayout table;
CalcGPA cal=new CalcGPA();

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_new:

            if (checked)
                x=1;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_old:
            if (checked)
                x=0;
            break;
    } }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    sub=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.subject);
    subject=sub.getText().toString();
    mark=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.marks);
    a=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mark));
    credit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.credits);
    b=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(credit));
    Adds=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.add_table);
    SUM=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.total_marks);
    GPA=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.s_gpa);
    percent=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.final_percentage);

    Adds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sub.setText("");
            mark.setText("");
            credit.setText("");
            counter++;
            hour +=b;
            if(x==0){
                gpa=cal.subgpa(a);
                grade=cal.Grade(a);
            }
            else if(x==1){
                gpa=cal.ChangedGpa(a);
                grade=cal.ChangedGrade(a);
            }
            add_row(subject,a,b,gpa,grade);
            gpa_multiple+=(gpa*b);
            SUM.setText(""+(counter*a));
            GPA.setText(""+(gpa_multiple/hour));
            percent.setText(""+((counter*a)/(counter*100)*100));


        }
    } );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public void add_row(String sub, int crdt, int marks, double sgpa, String subgrade  ){
    TableLayout tb = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_table);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView subject_name=new TextView(this);
    subject_name.setText(counter+""+sub);
    subject_name.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    subject_name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    TextView subject_marks=new TextView(this);
    subject_marks.setText(""+marks);
    subject_marks.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    subject_marks.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    TextView subject_credits=new TextView(this);
    subject_credits.setText(""+crdt);
    subject_credits.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    subject_credits.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    TextView subject_gpa=new TextView(this);
    subject_gpa.setText(""+sgpa);
    subject_gpa.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    subject_gpa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    TextView subject_grade=new TextView(this);
    subject_grade.setText(""+subgrade);
    subject_grade.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    subject_grade.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error and a runtime error here. 
Why are you parsing your content of your `EditText` in the `onCreate`() method?

just remove those two lines :

```
    //a = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mark));
    //b = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(credit));
```

First you don't need to parse them in the `onCreate` method. You parse the content in the `onClick`() method of your Button.
that was the logical error.
Second:

Your runtime error is being cause by the fact that you are trying to get the `valueOf` an `EditText` and not of a String. so `mark` should be replace by `mark.getText().toString()` and `credit` by `credit.getText().toString()`